# How to make im and diff commute

Tags: python, sympy

Differentiation of a real valued function of a real variable yields a real function. Taking the imaginary part of a real function returns 0, as expected

```
>>> class rho(Function):
        is_real=True

>>> var('t',real=True)
>>> im(rho(t))
0
```

However, taking the imaginary part of the derivative of the function does not

```
>>> im(diff(rho(t))
im(Derivative(rho(t),t))
```

How can I make these operations commute?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's an issue with making two operations commute, I think it's a syntax issue.

The class `Function` is a SymPy base class for all functions. If you look at this reference [**here**](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/About-implementing-special-functions), **in order to evaluate an instance of this class, we need an evaluation function in the body.**

```
from sympy import *

var('t',real=True)

class rho(Function):
    is_real = True

    # Missing part of your original rho function
    @classmethod
    def eval(cls,t):
        # e.g. 2*t, but any function of t works
        return 2*t

im(rho(t))
# Out: 0

im(diff(cos(t)))
# Out: 0
```

Initially, the result of calling `im(Derivative(rho(t),t))` was `im(Derivative(rho(t),t))`. This is the output for an [**unevaluated derivative.**](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/calculus.html) And this result makes sense, because we haven't defined how the function rho gets evaluated, so of course the `Derivative` function cannot evaluate it.

Comment: Then the problem is that re(diff(rho(t),t)) = 2t. I would like re(diff(rho(t),t))=diff(rho(t),t). From a mathematical perspective this makes sense based on the assumptions on rho and t.

Comment: I'm not sure that the specific result is attainable. In the SymPy documentation of the re function: "This function performs only elementary analysis and so it will fail to decompose properly more complicated expressions." http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.0/modules/functions.html